# What is the point of this line of code?

Tags: php, virtuemart

I found this line of code in the Virtuemart plugin for Joomla on line 2136 in administrator/components/com_virtuemart/classes/ps_product.php

```
eval ("\$text_including_tax = \"$text_including_tax\";");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scrap my previous answer.

The reason this eval() is here is shown in the [php eval docs](http://www.php.net/eval)

This is what's happening:

```
$text_including_tax = '$tax <a href="...">...</a>';

...

$tax = 10;

...

eval ("\$text_including_tax = \"$text_including_tax\";");
```

At the end of this `$text_including_tax` is equal to:

```
"10 <a href="...">...</a>"
```

The single quotes prevents `$tax` being included in the original definition of the string. By using `eval()` it forces it to re-evaluate the string and include the value for `$tax` in the string.

I'm not a fan of this particular method, but it is correct. An alternative could be to use `sprintf()`

Comment: It's still stupid to use eval. Coded differently they could have used sprintf or many different ways.

Comment: agreed - there are so many ways this could have been done better. It's kinda scary that this sort of thing is in a big public project like Joomla. You'd have thought it might have been using at least some level of best practices, but apparently not. Good thing it's open source so anyone can go any fix it. (anyone want to volunteer?)

Answer (score 4):

This code seems to be a bad way of forcing `$text_including_tax` to be a string.

The reason it is bad is because *if* `$text_including_tax` can contain data entered by a user it is possible for them to execute arbitrary code.

For example if `$text_include_tax` was set to equal:

```
"\"; readfile('/etc/passwd'); $_dummy = \"";
```

The eval would become:

```
eval("$text_include_tax = \"\"; readfile('/etc/passwd'); $_dummy =\"\";");
```

Giving the malicious user a dump of the passwd file.

A more correct method for doing this would be to cast the variable to string:

```
$text_include_tax = (string) $text_include_tax;
```

or even just:

```
$text_include_tax = "$text_include_tax";
```

If the data `$text_include_tax` is only an internal variable or contains already validated content there isn't a security risk. But it's still a bad way to convert a variable to a string because there are more obvious and safer ways to do it.

Comment: I was about to post the same thing ... there's no reason for using eval() in PHP.

Comment: In the context of the code itself it looks even stranger too.

$text_include_tax is set from the constant $VM_LANG->_PHPSHOP_INCLUDING_TAX which is defined as a string.

Looks like coding by coincidence to me.

Comment: Actually, I stand corrected. The actual reason is in my next post below.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that it's a funky way of forcing $text_including_tax to be a string and not a number.

Comment: Is there like (string) as to $string as (int) is it $int ?

Comment: yeah i belive there is. there is also is_string().

Comment: The much simpler $text_including_tax = "$text_including_tax" would do that. Why the eval then?

Comment: Yep, the eval() is totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's an attempt to cast the variable as a string? Just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the eval to get the tax rate into the output. Just moved this to a new server and for some reason this line caused a server error. As a quick fix, I changed it to:

```
//eval ("\$text_including_tax = \"$text_including_tax\";");
$text_including_tax = str_replace('$tax', $tax, $text_including_tax);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is evaluating the string as PHP code.

But it seems to be making a variable equal itself? Weird.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, it's code written by someone who doesn't know what on earth they're doing.

I also had a quick browse of the code to find a total lack of text escaping when putting HTML/URIs/etc. together. There are probably many injection holes to be found here in addition to the eval issues, if you can be bothered to audit it properly.

I would not want this code running on my server.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked through that codebase before. It's some of the worst PHP I have seen.

I imagine you'd do that kind of thing to cover up mistakes you made somewhere else.

Answer (score -4):

No, it's doing this:

Say `$text_including_tax` = "flat".  This code evaluates the line:

$flat = "flat";

It isn't necessarily good, but I did use a technique like this once to suck all the MySQL variables in an array like this:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $var = $row["Variable_name"];
        $$var = $row["Value"];
    }
```

Comment: It's escaping the first $ making it not the value of $text_including_tax.

Comment: it is still $text_including_tax = 'flat' here as first $ is escaped:
\$text_including_tax